# Sympy - Matrix .row_insert and .col_insert unexpected at pos = -1

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

Code:

```
from sympy import Matrix

Matrix([[1, 1], [1, 1]]).row_insert(-1, Matrix([[2,2]]))
```

Expected result:

```
Matrix([
[1, 1],
[1, 1],
[2, 2]])
```

Obtained result:

```
Matrix([
[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[1, 1]])
```

A similar unexpected result occurs with `.col_insert`. Why doesn't the `-1` index work as expected?

(Sympy version 1.6.2)

Comment: The `row_insert` method inserts rows before the existing row of that index so `row_insert(-1, V)` inserts a row *before* the last row. You can use `row_insert(M.shape[0], V)` or `vstack` to append rows.